# Reading numbers represented in both-endian format?

Tags: c#, endianness

Conceptually, I'm having a hard time understanding how a 32-bit unsigned integer (which is 4 bytes) can be represented as 8 bytes, the first four of which are encoded using the little-endian format and the last four of which are encoded using the big-endian format.

I'm specifically referring to the ISO 9660 format which encodes some 16-bit and 32-bit integers in this fashion.

I tried the following but this obviously does not work because the `BitConverter.ToUInt32()` method only takes the first four bytes from the starting index.

```
byte[] leastSignificant = reader.ReadBytes(4, Endianness.Little);
byte[] mostSignificant = reader.ReadBytes(4, Endianness.Big);

byte[] buffer = new byte[8];
Array.Copy(leastSignificant, 0, buffer, 0, 4);
Array.Copy(mostSignificant, 0, buffer, 4, 4);

uint actualValue = BitConverter.ToUInt32(buffer, 0);
```

What is the proper way to read a 32-bit unsigned integer represented as 8 bytes encoded in both-endian format?

Comment: ISO 9660, also referred to as CDFS (Compact Disc File System) in Microsoft Windows, is a file system standard published by the International Organization for Standardization (ISO) for optical disc media.

Comment: This goes back to the Intel design of the microprocessor.   An address is represented by a 16 bit segment register (MSB) and a 16 bit offset (LSB).  The offset came first and then the segment register 2nd, and the 16 bit number (2 bytes) were also swapped so the low byte came first and then the high byte.

Comment: @jdweng I'm not too knowledgeable about computer science/engineering, but what's the advantage of encoding an integer in this way? It takes up more space and it seems (to me) that it has no benefit.

Comment: If the number is actually stored twice, you'd only have to convert one representation of it.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis This is the problem I'm having. I'm not sure how I should be reading it, because I don't know how the value is stored. The description I have isn't specific enough about it. Although, it does say that on 32-bit machines, the last four bytes are skipped and in my mind, if a 32-bit machine can read only the first four bytes and get away with just that, than I should be able to as well, right?

Comment: The encoding was designed to optimize the speed of the hardware interface.  You are writing to a high speed disc and the hardware timing required this structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very typical for an ISO standard.  The organization is not very good at creating decent standards, only good at creating compromises among its members.  Two basic ways they do that, they either pick a sucky standard that makes everybody equally unhappy.  Or pick more than one so that everybody can be happy.  Encoding a number twice falls in the latter category.

There's *some* justification for doing it this way.  Optical disks have lots of bits that are very cheap to duplicate.  Their formats are often designed to keep the playback hardware as cheap as possible.  Mastering a disk is often *very* convoluted because of that, the BlueRay standard is particularly painful.

Since your machine is little-endian, you only care about the little-endian value.  Simply ignore the big-endian equivalent.  Technically you could add a check that they are the same but that's just wasted effort.

Comment: My machine actually is 64-bit but I was just saying that if a 32-bit machine can just read the first than a 64-bit could too. Anyways, so it's really just the same number encoded twice in two different ways?